# How does 馬 resemble a horse?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

Please see my 3 questions inscribed in the screenshot from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A6%AC):

[image]

Comment: other users also fail to see ＂head turned to look back"  (in the earliest version) which is not in Chinese, nor French version: 
颈有鬃，尾有长毛，有蹄，四肢强健。性温驯。
Image d'un cheval, dont on voit la tête (réduite à un œil), la crinière, quatre pattes et la queue.

Comment: Could you please copy the actual questions in the text part of your question? This would make the question more accessible to people with visual impairments.

Answer (score 4):

the character [馬](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%A6%AC) existed in oracle bone script, there're numerous versions of it. then, the info quoted has some errors.

let's start:

[image]

first, rotate left 90°

[image]

now, you've a side view of a horse: head at the left, tail pointing right, 3 strokes upward represent the mane, the circles are horseshoe, the line (leg) connected it to the body.

it emphasised the big eye of a horse, the mane on its' back, and the "hairy" of a horsetail.

considering it's created several thousand years ago, with the "writing tech" of bones & stone knife, forgive the abstractness :)

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

If Picasso had painted it that way, it would be worth $50 million dollars! One must allow for artistic license, not demand 100% depictual accuracy, especially when scratching in tortoise shells! Also Wiktionary may err from time to often.

Have a look [here](https://image.baidu.com/search/detail?ct=503316480&z=0&ipn=d&word=%E9%A9%AC%E5%AD%97%E7%9A%84%E5%8E%9F%E6%9D%A5&step_word=&hs=0&pn=0&spn=0&di=155562526681&pi=0&rn=1&tn=baiduimagedetail&is=0%2C0&istype=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&in=&cl=2&lm=-1&st=undefined&cs=748579235%2C552334805&os=2084884917%2C173652846&simid=3596994304%2C390828847&adpicid=0&lpn=0&ln=1948&fr=&fmq=1511737609209_R&fm=&ic=undefined&s=undefined&se=&sme=&tab=0&width=undefined&height=undefined&face=undefined&ist=&jit=&cg=&bdtype=0&oriquery=&objurl=http%3A%2F%2Fimg.taopic.com%2Fuploads%2Fallimg%2F131216%2F234716-131216214S197.jpg&fromurl=ippr_z2C%24qAzdH3FAzdH3Fooo_z%26e3Bpw5rtv_z%26e3Bv54AzdH3Fejvp56AzdH3Fda8n8dAzdH3F99l0nc_z%26e3Bip4s&gsm=0&rpstart=0&rpnum=0).

Comment: Your "here" link is not loading for me.

Comment: just look in baidu images 马字